# unable to uplaod an image in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I tried to upload image using Laravel controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new=new Verify;
        $new->user_id=Auth::id();
        $new->message=$request->message;
        if($request->hasfile('image'))
        {
            $file=$request->file('image');
            $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename=time() ."." . $extension;
            $file->move('uploads/Verify',$filename);
            $new->image=$filename;

        }
        $new->save();
        return redirect()->back();
```

my migration tables looks like this

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('verifies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('message')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

fields like user id and message are getting filled but the image field remains the null 
the html of the code is such as

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>Your message</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<form action="{{route('Verifying')}}" method="POST">
@csrf

<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="5" rows="5"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Your Cnic</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit">
</td>
</tr>
</form>

</table>
```

can anyone guide me what is wrong ? why image is not uploading...

Comment: you are not uploading a file .. your form is not setup to handle multiple part form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form send with the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` then it should works

```
<form action="{{route('Verifying')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

then It will work
**Why we add the `enctype`**
The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.